# Unable to compile project from Maven Central

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am trying to compile an older version (2.4.0) of the gwt-servlet project from Maven Central.  I have done the following:

1) Downloaded [gwt-servlet-2.4.0-sources.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.4.0/gwt-servlet-2.4.0-sources.jar) from Maven Central.

2) Extracted this source .jar into an empty **C:/workingdir/src/main/java** directory.

3) Downloaded [gwt-servlet-2.4.0.pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.4.0/gwt-servlet-2.4.0.pom) from Maven Central to **C:/workingdir/pom.xml**

4) Executed mvn clean, then mvn install.

On mvn install, I get 100 errors and a handful of warnings from the compiler:

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gwt-servlet 2.4.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-beta-1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ gwt-servlet ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gwt-servlet ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\workingdir\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gwt-servlet ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3041 source files to C:\workingdir\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/server/CommandSerializationUtil.java:[36,16] sun.misc.Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/rebind/context/AbstractResourceContext.java:[43,13] sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/rebind/context/AbstractResourceContext.java:[43,46] sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/server/CommandSerializationUtil.java:[438,24] sun.misc.Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/server/CommandSerializationUtil.java:[442,5] sun.misc.Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/server/CommandSerializationUtil.java:[444,17] sun.misc.Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/server/CommandSerializationUtil.java:[446,22] sun.misc.Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParsers.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParsers.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/ArrayList.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/ArrayList.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[WARNING] Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
[INFO] 12 warnings
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/validation/super/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtMessageInterpolator.java:[25,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.validation.client.GwtMessageInterpolator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/user/translatable/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/core/java/util/LinkedHashMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:[29,14] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.LinkedHashMap_Custo                        mFieldSerializer
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/regexp/super/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/MatchResult.java:[23,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.MatchResult
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/super/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/impl/StringQuoter.java:[33,8] duplicate class: com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/client/impl/ClientWriterFactory.java:[35,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.rpc.client.impl.ClientWriterFactory
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/junit/client/GWTTestCase.java:[48,17] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/benchmarks/translatable/com/google/gwt/benchmarks/client/Benchmark.java:[24,17] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.benchmarks.client.Benchmark
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/ReflectionHelper.java:[29,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ReflectionHelper
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/super/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/ValueCodexHelper.java:[21,1] duplicate class: com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.ValueCodexHelper
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/super/com/google/gwt/rpc/client/impl/EscapeUtil.java:[25,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.rpc.client.impl.EscapeUtil
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtConfiguration.java:[31,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.validation.client.GwtConfiguration
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/safehtml/super/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlHostedModeUtils.java:[22,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlHostedModeUtils
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/super/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/impl/MessageFactoryHolder.java:[24,8] duplicate class: com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.MessageFactoryHo                        lder
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/junit/client/impl/GWTRunner.java:[31,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/WeakMapping.java:[30,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.WeakMapping
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.java:[39,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/validation/client/spi/GwtConfigurationState.java:[27,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.validation.client.spi.GwtConfigurationState
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeUriHostedModeUtils.java:[34,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeUriHostedModeUtils
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/regexp/super/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/SplitResult.java:[23,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.SplitResult
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[19,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[20,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[68,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[19,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[20,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[69,7] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JMethod
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[69,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[81,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleFields.java:[18,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[82,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[88,15] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[89,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[96,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[97,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[104,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleRequirements.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleRequirements.java:[19,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[105,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JMethod
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceGenerator.java:[106,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGenerator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[60,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceContext
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[79,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceContext
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[97,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceContext
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[115,3] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JClassType
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceContext
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ResourceContext.java:[124,3] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GeneratorContext
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceContext
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleFields.java:[44,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ClientBundleFields
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleFields.java:[60,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ClientBundleFields
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleRequirements.java:[40,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BadPropertyValueException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ClientBundleRequirements
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleRequirements.java:[59,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BadPropertyValueException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ClientBundleRequirements
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/resources/ext/ClientBundleRequirements.java:[94,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JClassType
  location: interface com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ClientBundleRequirements
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/i18n/rebind/keygen/MD5KeyGenerator.java:[18,40] package com.google.gwt.util.tools.shared does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/StrictAttributeParser.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/StrictAttributeParser.java:[19,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/FieldReferenceConverter.java:[18,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParser.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[19,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[19,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[20,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[21,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[22,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/StrictAttributeParser.java:[68,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.attributeparsers.StrictAttributeParser
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/StrictAttributeParser.java:[70,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.attributeparsers.StrictAttributeParser
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/StrictAttributeParser.java:[84,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.attributeparsers.StrictAttributeParser
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager.java:[19,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager.java:[20,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager.java:[21,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager.java:[22,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParser.java:[34,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: interface com.google.gwt.uibinder.attributeparsers.AttributeParser
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[71,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.MortalLogger
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[73,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.MortalLogger
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[82,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.MortalLogger
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[91,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.MortalLogger
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[96,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TreeLogger
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.MortalLogger
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger.java:[114,38] package TreeLogger does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParsers.java:[18,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParsers.java:[19,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParsers.java:[20,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/AttributeParsers.java:[21,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/BundleAttributeParsers.java:[18,31] package com.google.gwt.core.ext does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/BundleAttributeParsers.java:[19,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/BundleAttributeParsers.java:[20,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/BundleAttributeParsers.java:[21,40] package com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[135,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeOracle
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[144,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[145,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[146,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[147,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[148,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[149,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[175,7] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeOracle
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[193,43] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[214,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[230,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[249,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[250,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[266,7] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JType
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/XMLElement.java:[266,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnableToCompleteException
  location: class com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.XMLElement
[INFO] 100 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 32.595 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-03T01:21:33-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/645M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project gwt-servlet: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/validation/super/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtMessageInterpolator.java:[25,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.validation.client.GwtMessageInterpolator
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/user/translatable/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/core/java/util/LinkedHashMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:[29,14] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.LinkedHashMap_Custo                        mFieldSerializer
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/regexp/super/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/MatchResult.java:[23,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.MatchResult
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/super/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/impl/StringQuoter.java:[33,8] duplicate class: com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/client/impl/ClientWriterFactory.java:[35,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.rpc.client.impl.ClientWriterFactory
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/junit/client/GWTTestCase.java:[48,17] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/benchmarks/translatable/com/google/gwt/benchmarks/client/Benchmark.java:[24,17] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.benchmarks.client.Benchmark
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/ReflectionHelper.java:[29,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ReflectionHelper
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/super/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/ValueCodexHelper.java:[21,1] duplicate class: com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.ValueCodexHelper
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/rpc/super/com/google/gwt/rpc/client/impl/EscapeUtil.java:[25,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.rpc.client.impl.EscapeUtil
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtConfiguration.java:[31,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.validation.client.GwtConfiguration
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/safehtml/super/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlHostedModeUtils.java:[22,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlHostedModeUtils
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/super/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/impl/MessageFactoryHolder.java:[24,8] duplicate class: com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.MessageFactoryHo                        lder
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/junit/client/impl/GWTRunner.java:[31,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/WeakMapping.java:[30,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.WeakMapping
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.java:[39,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp
[ERROR] /C:/workingdir/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/validation/client/spi/GwtConfigurationState.java:[27,8] duplicate class: com.google.gwt.validation.client.spi.GwtConfigurationState
```

.. and on and on

Maven info:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: C:\tmp\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I have tried running Maven with an older jdk (jdk1.6.0_45) and have tried compiling other version of gwt-servlet with no luck.  Am I missing something?  I have been trying every whichway to get this to compile all day.  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you like to build an version from maven Central? It's already there and compiled so why not simply consuming it?

Comment: @khmarbaise Because I need to customize one of the classes in the library and rebuild it.

Comment: Ah ok...but on one hand I would create an issue on the project and I would start with the source repository and not with the source jar from Central....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably check out the [2.4.0](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt.git/+/2.4.0) tag and build that instead.

It seems (I may be wrong) this version was not even build with Maven, at least no `pom.xml`s are seen. So it is not a surprise it can't be built with Maven.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I assumed since it was on Maven Central and had a .pom there as well that it had been built via Maven and put out there.  Thanks again.